# How do I create and name an object at run time?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, instance

I have a class called studentInfo:

```
#pragma once
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class studentInfo
{
public:
    //constructors
    studentInfo() {}
    studentInfo(string n, int a, string g);

    void printDetails();

private:
    string name;
    string gender;
    int age;
};
```

.cpp file:

```
#include "studentInfo.h"
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

studentInfo::studentInfo(string n, int a, string g)
{
    name = n;
    age = a;
    gender = g;
}

void studentInfo::printDetails()
{
    std::cout << "Name: " << name << "\nAge: " << age << "\nGender: " << gender << endl;
}
```

So I know how to create an instance using a constructor, eg: `studentInfo s1182("Ollie", 19, "Male");` but is there a way I can do it at run time and have the instance named by a user input?
Something along the lines of:

```
string ID;
cin >> ID;

studentInfo *what ID is*("Bob", 18, "Male");
```

So that then if the ID entered was s2212 that instance would be named s2212, meaning I could do `s2212.printDetails()`

Comment: This is not possible. Take a look at `std::map`.

Comment: Not exactly, but if you are not using inheritance you could put those in a map with string keys. Inheritance would complicate matters but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: You can't "name" a variable at run-time, it's simply not possible. And why would you want to anyway? Perhaps what you're looking for is some kind of dictionary or container in general to store the objects?

Comment: Your program would have to generate the C++ code, compile that new code, and then execute that new executable.  Not a typical way of doing things in C++, although there are certain specialized use cases that do something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is using a map like this

```
string ID;
cin >> ID;

map<string, studentInfo> students;

if(students.find(ID) == students.end())
   students[ID] = studentInfo("Bob", 18, "Male");
```

P.S.: There are all sorts of ways of inserting an entry into map. Read the [reference manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: As an aside, there are languages where what you ask is possible. See `JavaScript`'s `eval()`.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible. Identifiers cannot be determined at runtime.

Something that may be close to what you're trying is to use an associative map from string name to student object.